How to determine what is opening tmp files when I invoke a subshell with ksh
I'm experiencing extremely sluggishness in opening subshells (by using ` ` or $( ) command substitutions in scripts) while in ksh on some Linux servers. The same problem does not exist in sh or any other shell. strace indicates that the time is due to stat and openat calls against randomly named files in /tmp.
test.sh:
echo `expr 1 + 1`

command:
strace -tttT ksh test.sh

output:
. . .[snipped]. . .
1734368858.571604 stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=708608, ...}) = 0 <0.613038>
1734368859.184765 geteuid()             = 1001 <0.000011>
1734368859.184851 getegid()             = 1002 <0.000008>
1734368859.184879 getuid()              = 1001 <0.000013>
1734368859.184913 getgid()              = 1002 <0.000007>
1734368859.184946 access("/tmp", W_OK|X_OK) = 0 <0.000020>
1734368859.185012 getpid()              = 210594 <0.000009>
1734368859.185055 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/sf0p.si0", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = 1 <1.586349>
1734368860.771539 unlink("/tmp/sf0p.si0") = 0 <0.008521>
. . .

Between stat and openat, my simple invocation of expr 1 + 1 took more than 2 seconds of time.
Questions:

Why is ksh creating files in /tmp, whereas none of the other shells (sh, bash, csh) do that?
How do I start diagnosing why these operations would take 1-2 seconds?

Server in question is at version: Linux 5.4.17-2136.322.6.4.el8uek.x86_64 (distribution Oracle Linux Server release 8.9). Ksh is version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
Update:
We've seen some artifacts of python creating empty directories under /tmp, which a few days ago I found to number 10,000 subdirs under /tmp. I deleted them all but it did not help performance. Forgive my lack of Unix knowledge, but am I right in assuming that once the directory inode is enlarged to list such an extensive # of subdirs/files, deleting those doesn't shrink the directory inode itself, but leaves a sparse structure that still has to be scanned through by all file accesses? The inode size of my /tmp (ls -ld /tmp) is currently 708KB. That's 172x larger than the starting size of 4096 bytes. Could that be what's slowing down stat and openat calls that hit /tmp ?

you'd start by figuring out what kind of filesystem is mounted on /tmp, e.g. by running df -h -T /tmp.

@MarcusMüller  /dev/mapper/VGExaDb-LVDbTmp xfs

Oh! Often these days, you get a tmpfs there! So, first suspicion is the underlying storage going wrong. does dmesg -Hwx contain any indication of storage problems? Would strace -T touch /tmp/somerandomstring also take so long?

@MarcusMüller the simple touch does take long, yes. strace shows the time in the openat call. As for dmesg, while I do have access to run that, I don't know how to interpret it. This is an Exadata compute node, set up this way by Oracle. If I touch a file in my home dir, which is also an xfs mapped to the same storage I'm guessing (based on the similarity of what df shows), it's fast. The problem is only when hitting /tmp.

ah! In that case, do you have a support you can escalate this to? A simple touch taking > 1s is a clear indication of something being wrong; in this case, something that only someone with the (organizational) privileges to replace storage volumes has a chance of fixing. If you are in fact that person and have nobdody to escalate to, you'd have to look more closely into what your storage setup state is.

@shellter, added

@MarcusMüller, please see my update.. any thoughts?

@PaulW you worry too much at filesystem level, XFS specifically has excellent behaviour when it comes to searching even large directories, and deleting a lot of entries would also inherently remove all tree structures and hence metadata extents no longer used. 10000 is "not that many" subdirectories for XFS. The size is, however, still large. But riddle me this: how long does your computer take to compile 700 kB of C source code? milliseconds, maybe, on a bad day? The filesystem structures of XFS are made for rapid parsing, unlike C. So, something taking > 1s is simply outrageous.

What sort of backend is /tmp on?  I've seen slowness like this when the blockstore is from a shared block device (eg from ceph, perhaps via librbd to provide blocks to the VM, which you can then put XFS on top of).   Although 1 second is a little large even for that setup!

Have you tried setting TMPDIR to point to a read-only directory and looking to see what complains?

ksh93 will generate temporary files if the command execution is an external command.  So, for example
a=$(echo hello)

will not generate a temp file, but
a=$(/bin/echo hello)

does.
e.g.
$ cat x                       
a=$(echo hello)

$ strace ksh x 2>&1 | grep tmp

$ cat y
a=$(/bin/echo hello)

$ strace ksh y 2>&1 | grep tmp
stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=36864, ...}) = 0
access("/tmp", W_OK|X_OK)               = 0
open("/tmp/sf0q.l29", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = 1
unlink("/tmp/sf0q.l29") 

What is interesting is that this follows standard $TMPDIR environment settings (see man 3 tempnam).
e.g
$ TMPDIR=/var/tmp strace ksh y 2>&1 | grep tmp    
stat("/var/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/var/tmp", W_OK|X_OK)           = 0
open("/var/tmp/sf1f.5hq", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = 1
unlink("/var/tmp/sf1f.5hq")

This can allow you to move these temporary files to faster locations (eg tmpfs, maybe /run ?) or areas with less disk contention in a busy environment.
When running an external command (eg /bin/echo in this example), ksh will create this temporary file, set the stdout of the command to the filehandle, delete the file.  The output of the command is sent to this deleted file, and then this is read in to get the results.  When the command has completed and data read in the deleted file will be cleaned up.  I assume this is a memory saving attempt.
Other shells may behave differently because they're different code bases.

TMPDIR sounds promising, giving it a try now!
